# What is the color of a forfeit?

Tags: swiss-pairing

Again, wonders of Swiss.

Before the last round, I had bwbwbbwf. My opponent had bwbwbwbw.
The f wasn't a colorless bye (I'd give up chess then :-) but a forfeit after pairings were out (due to sudden sickness of my R8 opponent). Is a forfeit unconditionally as colorless as a bye? (In that case, the colors are obvious, since my preference is strong w and my R9 opponent's weak b.) I read [§C042D5](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/C0402) as affirmative of that assertion, am I correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FIDE document [C.04.2 General handling rules for Swiss Tournaments](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/C0402) gives the answer:

> Only played games count in situations where the colour sequence is meaningful. So, for instance, a player with a colour history of BWB=W (i.e. no valid game in round-4) will be treated as if his colour history was =BWBW. WB=WB will count as =WBWB, BWW=B=W as ==BWWBW and so on.

Hence your "bwbwbbwf" converts to "bwbwbbw=" in the notation of the document and that will be treated as if your colour history was "=bwbwbbw". So you will have a strong preference for white, as you say.